# Driving a low resistance load with PWM

Tags: power-supply, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

I have been trying to build a simple PWM power supply to use a 3.7v battery to drive a small heating element with a DC resistance of about 1 ohm.  I have built a slightly modified version of the following LT3759 based circuit:

[image: lt3759]
<sub>(source: [linear.com](https://cds.linear.com/image/9248.png))</sub>

I modified the circuit for an output voltage of 5.0V.

I have no problem getting the expected behavior from the circuit on my scope with a large load, in the kOhm range.  When I try to drive the heating element I want, the voltage drops to about 400mV.

I suspected this might be some sort of impedance issue, so I put a simple voltage follower with a mosfet at the output, but this failed to resolve my issue.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?  I am guessing it is something trivial that I am missing due to my lack of background in this area.

Comment: You can use LTSpice tool to verify and tune the circuit, Since its LT part you get models and spice files easily...

Comment: I have the same problem as you, with a low resistance unit, just cannot the right output. Have you figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Your 1 ohm heating element will want 5 amps from a 5 volt supply.  That drawing indicates the circuit is only good for 500 mA output with an input voltage less than 8 volts.

If the circuit could deliver the required 5 volts, it would attempt to draw about 6.75 Amps from the 3.7 volt battery.  Can the battery deliver that current?